# VSCode Code folding Error

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-folding

After I update Visual Studio Code to the latest version (version 1.22, refer: [Release Note for Visual Studio Code 1.22](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_22)), the code folding does not work. It looks like the folding does not work for `else if` statement.

Here is what I mean:
[no folding for else if statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3xyU.png)

[but code folding here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viRXh.png)

Comment: What language are you using? 请问你是使用什么语言？JavaScript?

Comment: @user3454439  yes，but that bug is resolved

Answer (score 7):

In VS Code editor settings add this

```
"editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using latest version (version 1.22) of VSCode as well. For JavaScript I am working on, I find out when the `else if` is like this:

```
} else if (...) {
```

The code folding does not work. However if I move the `else` to next line:

```
}
else if (...) {
```

The code folder does work.

Maybe you could consider moving the `else if` to next line?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. Please file a new issue against vscode [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues).

The fix is likely to disable syntax aware folding by setting:

```
"typescript.experimental.syntaxFolding": false,
```