# Folding strategy does not work on Visual Studio Code, why?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VS Code installed (1.83.1) and folding does not work properly.

Here are 2 pictures of my code (it is a ~5k line python file) where folding does not work as I expect.

#### Example 1

[image: Example 1]

#### Example 2

*Not folded*
[image: Example 2]
*When folded, R_R_CH disappears, which is not what I expect*
[image: Example b2]

I have defined the folding strategy in my settings like this : `"editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"` as recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74211442/15060764) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51806811/15060764).

But it only works on one computer, not the other one, with the same files.

On both computers, current version of VS Code is 1.83.1.

Comment: ... what's wrong? your second screenshot looks like it's working as intended. what do you expect to see there? also, we need a [mre].

Comment: I can see what's wrong with the first example, but I still don't see what's wrong with the second example. And I'm still waiting on a [mre]- something I can _copy and paste_ to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am still looking on how to write a minimal reproductible example. For now, I don't know how to reproduce the folding problem ...